# Properties of $H$ and Properties of $G/H$ involving Order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $G$ is a group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $m$ be  a fixed integer. $x^m \in H$ for every $x \in G$ iff the order of every element in $G/H$ is a divisor of $m$.

I'm not quite sure what to make of this. I believe we can begin with:

IF: Suppose some $(x_1)^m \in H$ then ord$(x_1)=\frac{m}{Hx}$. I know $H=Hx$ since $x \in H$ (unless being $x^m$ is different then being $x$).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question.  Please also do that for your old questions. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

"$\Leftarrow$" If ord$(xH)$ divides $m$ then $(xH)^m=x^mH=H$, so what can you say about $x^m$?

"$\Rightarrow$" Should follow easily if you understand "$\Leftarrow$".

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow but would this just say that $x^m \in H$ since $x^mH=H$?

Comment: Indeed. If $x^mH=H$, then the sets $\{x^mh\ |\ h\in H\}$ and $H$ are the same. So, in particular, $e\in x^mH$, so the inverse of $x^m$ as an element of $G$ is in $H$ somewhere. But $H$ is also a group, so $x^m\in H$.

Comment: So since we have proved the one way, should we can begin with assuming $x^m \in xH$ to prove the other way?

Comment: Careful, to prove "$\Rightarrow$" the assumption is $x^m\in H$, not $x^m\in xH$.

Comment: If $x^m \in H$ then would $xx^m \in xH$? Like $x^{m+1}$

Comment: Yes, that's true.